# Parameteres in request always 'null'

Tags: html, servlets

I have done this before, but can't get it work this time :S

I have a JSP with a form:

```
    <form action="/SimModSystem-web/ExecuteModel" method="post">
            <h2>Initial State</h2>
    <h3>ASSET</h3>
    <div  style="style0"><span style="style1">Assets Amount</span><span style="style2"><span style="style2">Amount<input type="text" value="[-Infinite - +Infinite]" id="initial..asset.amount.param0" /></span></span></div>
    <div  style="style0"><span style="style1">Savings Interest APR</span><span style="style2"><span style="style2">APR %<input type="text" value="[0.0 - 1.0]" id="initial..asset.apr.param0" /></span></span></div>
    <div  style="style0"><span style="style1">Desired Savings Percentage</span><span style="style2"><span style="style2">Annual %<input type="text" value="[0.0 - 1.0]" id="initial..asset.minsaving.param0" /></span></span></div>
    <h3>LIABILITY</h3>
    <div  style="style0"><span style="style1">Liabilities Monthly Minimum Payment Percentage</span><span style="style2"><span style="style2">Minimum Payment %<input type="text" value="[0.0 - 1.0]" id="initial..liabilities.minpay.param0" /></span></span></div>
    <div  style="style0"><span style="style1">Liabilities Amount</span><span style="style2"><span style="style2">Amount<input type="text" value="[0.0 - +Infinite]" id="initial..liabilities.amount.param0" /></span></span></div>
    <div  style="style0"><span style="style1">Liabilities APR</span><span style="style2"><span style="style2">APR %<input type="text" value="[0.0 - 1.0]" id="initial..liabilities.apr.param0" /></span></span></div>
    <div  style="style0"><span style="style1">Liabilities Delayed Payment Fee</span><span style="style2"><span style="style2">Fee Amount<input type="text" value="[0.0 - +Infinite]" id="initial..liabilities.delayedfee.param0" /></span></span></div>
...
<input type="submit"/>
        </form>
```

When I click "submit", in the servlet when I try to do:

```
request.getParameterNames();
request.getParameterMap();
request.getParateter("initial..liabilities.delayedfee.param0"); //or any other param
```

All return 'null'.

As you can see there is no special encoding in this form.

Does anyone knows what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use name of component, just "id" won't work

```
<input type="text" value="[-Infinite - +Infinite]" id="initial..asset.amount.param0" name="comp1" />
```

And

```
request.getParameter("comp1");
```

Comment: Thanks man! I knew it was a silly thing but couldn't realize it by myself :S

Comment: You are welcome. I learned from same mistake. Enjoy coding. If answer helped you, don't forget to accept it.